# Making ext4 partition without mount point during installation and then mount it my self

Tags: debian

Hello I have 256GB SSD and 1TB HDD.
I want to make dual boot with Windows 10 & Linux Mint, but want to make 1 ext4 partition on my HDD without mount point and then mount it myself with name such as `/storage`. I will use this as storage to download torrents.

So my partition scheme should look something like that:

```
SSD
___________________
Drive C: -primary
/ -ext4 -primary
/home -ext4 -primary
/var -ext4 -primary

HDD
__________________
Drive D: -primary
swap partition
ext4 -primary (without mount point, going to make mount point after the installation, like /storage)
```

And this are the steps that I will proceed to do:

1. Install Windows end create drive C: on the SSD and Drive D: on the HDD using the windows manager.
2. After Windows is installed, install Linux Mint and create partitions `/`, `/home`, `/var` on the SSD and swap and one ext4 partition without mount point during the Linux Installation tool.
3. After Linux is installed, make sure both system are installed and working in dual boot, then make a mount point for the ext4 partition in the HDD.

My question is, could I get to some problems, because of making ext4 partition without setting a mount point during the installation? And also how to make it permanently mounted after the installation of my Linux OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are any problems with the installer you can just omit the creation of this partition and do that later. That can be done by e.g. `cfdisk` and `parted`.

1. Create the partition.
2. Create the filesystem in the partition (assuming the new one is sda6):

   ```
   mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda6
   ```
3. Create the mointpoint:

   ```
   mkdir --mode=000 /storage
   ```
4. Add the partition to `/etc/fstab` (according to the other entries, e.g.):

   ```
   /dev/sda6   /storage    ext4    defaults    0 2
   # or
   # UUID=...  /storage    ext4    defaults    0 2
   ```

   You may want to use the UUID instead of the device file, see `blkid /dev/sda6`.

Comment: So I can skip making empty ext4 partition during the installation, that have no mount point and just use gparted to make such partition after the installation, and add it to fstab to make it permanently mounted automatically when the OS is loaded ?

Comment: @VelikoKosev Yes, that's what I said.